# getCalculatedValue reports different response to exported spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am working with a fairly large, complex spreadsheet (there are 6 sheets, each with 200-400 rows) and am having trouble getting the correct values out of some cells.

My workflow is roughly:

1. User data is inputted on front-end
2. Data is validated and then placed into certain cells on the spreadsheet
3. Calculations in other cells reference the user-input cells
4. I use `getCalculatedValue` on particular cells to retrieve the necessary values
5. For debug purposes I then save out the modified spreadsheet so that I can easily see that the data has been inputted and generated correctly.

PHPExcel has been working great, but I have ran into an issue where the `getCalculatedValue` method (step 4) is returning an incorrect value, but when I inspect the spreadsheet that has been saved out (step 5) the values are correct.

The calculations consist of general mathematical equations, IF conditions, some date manipulation and multiple VLOOKUPs.

I am currently picking my way through the calculations in order to trace the issue, but was wondering if there may be a simpler solution to this that I am not aware of. Perhaps some setting that affects the outcome of various different calculations? This may even be a subtle change in calculations that is subsequently snow-balling into a bigger change further down the line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a syntax error in the spreadsheet that I was provided.

A `round` function was being used like so:

> ROUND(NUMBER,)

Excel compensated for this by using 0 as the second parameter, whereas PHPExcel (quite correctly) didn't.